# Cálculo de crescimento anual - PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Fiz o agrupamento da soma do faturamento dos dois anos que vou comparar.

```
select
(extract (year from date_key)) as Ano,
sum(faturamento) as Faturamento_Anual
from public.tabela_1
group by 1
```

Mas não sei como faço na query o comparativo de crescimento.

Comment: Veja se ajuda window function e lead e lag .. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html   https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o trecho apresentado em um [mcve] do problema de forma que a postagem fique completa para outros usuários com problema similar, preferencialmente descrevendo o que tentou para resolver  e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html#TUTORIAL-WINDOW)

Dessa forma você pode calcular o faturamento do ano anterior na mesma query e então calcular a diferença ou o crescimento percentual.

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE Faturamento (
  date_key DATE NOT NULL,
  faturamento NUMERIC NOT NULL
);


-- insert
INSERT INTO Faturamento (date_key, faturamento) VALUES
('2021-01-01', 10000),
('2021-02-01', 15000),
('2021-03-01', 20000),
('2022-01-01', 12000),
('2022-02-01', 18000),
('2022-03-01', 25000),
('2023-01-01', 13000),
('2023-02-01', 19000),
('2023-03-01', 26000);


-- fetch 
WITH Faturamento_Anual AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_key) AS Ano,
    SUM(faturamento) AS Faturamento_Anual
  FROM Faturamento
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
  Ano,
  Faturamento_Anual,
  LAG(Faturamento_Anual) OVER (ORDER BY Ano) AS Faturamento_Anterior,
  Faturamento_Anual - LAG(Faturamento_Anual) OVER (ORDER BY Ano) AS Diferenca,
  (Faturamento_Anual - LAG(Faturamento_Anual) OVER (ORDER BY Ano)) / LAG(Faturamento_Anual) OVER (ORDER BY Ano) * 100 AS Crescimento_Percentual
FROM Faturamento_Anual
ORDER BY Ano;
```

https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/424yxuyv6

```
Output:

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
 ano  | faturamento_anual | faturamento_anterior | diferenca | crescimento_percentual  
------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------------------
 2021 |             45000 |                      |           |                        
 2022 |             55000 |                45000 |     10000 | 22.22222222222222222200
 2023 |             58000 |                55000 |      3000 |  5.45454545454545454500
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Lembrando que esta síntaxe , com pequenas alterações talvez , funciona em Oracle , SqlServer e Mysql.